# Sending ^C over PySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm writing an automated script to reset the password on a Cisco 1800 series router. In order to begin the reset process, you must enter the ROMMON by sending a break when the ROMMON is initialized. For the life of me, I cannot send a break over PySerial, no matter how hard I try. Here is the code I've been using:

```
import serial, time
effinByte = '\x03'
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=1.0, rtscts=False)
if(ser.isOpen() == False):
    ser.open()
    print("Opening port")
else:
    print("Port already open")
isNotResetting = True
while isNotResetting == True:
    print("Waiting for ROMMON")
    theOutput = ser.readline()
        if ("ROMMON" in theOutput):
                ser.write(effingByte.encode('ascii'))
                print ('Mr. Meeseeks find!')

                while True:
                        print ser.readline()
```

Basically, it waits for the 'initializing ROMMON' line and tries to send a break.

Comment: Do you want to send a break or a control-C? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Try to write `'\x03'` without encoding it to ascii, from my experience it should work.

Comment: @Robᵩ I want to send a break.

Comment: @Arengorn I have, this is my other attempt

Answer (score 0):

sendBreak(self) is the answer. I'm so stupid!